# Run AppleScript in background without showing in app switcher?

Tags: macos, mac, applescript, dock, ui

Is there any way to run an **AppleScript command** (which runs infinitely) **completely in the background** without any icon showing in the dock or app switcher (⌘+Tab)?

For example, hiding the AppleScript icon here. (The script was exported to a run-only application)

[image]

---

Any ideas/advice is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have access to the contents of the command – the AppleScript text itself? If so, you can [run the script](https://www.dssw.co.uk/blog/2011-05-22-how-to-run-a-shell-script-every-day-on-a-mac/) using the command line tool `osascript`.

Comment: Adding `LSUIElement -bool yes` to the app's Info.plist file will hide it in the Dock and therefore will not show in the App Switcher.  In Terminal, basically it's e.g.: `defaults write '/Applications/AppName.app/Contents/Info.plist' LSUIElement -bool yes`

Comment: I am almost certain that, whatever your AppleScript is doing, a run-only app that runs forever is not going to be the best way to do it.  So I think if you posted your script, someone could not only tell you how to get it out of the app switcher, but implement it using another method (likely `launchd`).